# What happens to the electrons at junction?

Tags: electricity

In a Closed circuit at any wire junction, one end of a wire is bound to an end of another wire . Now the Circuit is closed. So the electrons are passing through the wire. Now  at the junction there is macroscopical contact but microscopiclly a large gap between the two wire.
Now what happens to these electrons ?

**1.Are they really exiting one wire's surface and entering into others ? How do the particles overcome the gap ?**

**2.** **Is it still possible, if the emf of the battery is lower, say 1 V, that does not allow the electrons to have energy more than their work function to get out from the wire's surface?**

**But at 1 V , still current passes ?**

In short , **What happens to the electrons at junction?**

Comment: Why do you think there is always a microscopic gap?

Comment: Electrons don't leak out of the wire like water from a pipe

Comment: There is no gap between the metals, instead you have (usually many) microscopic areas where the wires touch at atomic distances comparable to the lattice constant, i.e. the metals come close enough for the electrons to move from one metal to the other. The microscopic description is not totally trivial, of course, because for different metals Fermi levels may be different, leading to thermoelectric potential differences and, if oxide layers are present there can be diode-like effects (this was used in early radios before true semiconductor diodes were invented).